# Is it possible to remove the Tabbar background and box?

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

[image]
I have created a tabbar application, but I was wondering is it possible to remove the color of the background and the frame box. Just to leave it empty and the user sees only the tab buttons "search" and "more", something like a "snapchat" on the bottom. I tried to make it white, but stills it is visible for the users, since there is a frame and the colors are different.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
    let tabBarAppearace = UITabBar.appearance()
    tabBarAppearace.tintColor           = UIColor.clearColor()
    tabBarAppearace.shadowImage         = UIImage()
    tabBarAppearace.backgroundImage     = UIImage()
```

If you need to change it dependent on what view you're looking at you can try this:

```
static func appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses(containerTypes: [AnyObject.Type]) -> Self
```

Check out [this awesome post](http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/) from NSHipster that explains it in more depth.

Comment: hey thank you very much, it seems that it is working perfect, only would you tell me how to make the tapped button visible. Look at the pic I uploaded, in this case, the "search" button should be white.

Comment: I managed to fix that problem with the white color, but I have another question. I used your code in the AppDelegate and it is applied to all of the viewcontrollers, but how can I use it only for a specific one. I tried to put it in the viewdDidLoad in the viewcontroller where I need it but nothing is happening. Is it really possible to apply it only for one?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. I tried to use it in the viewDidLoad of the view controller where I need it, but when I tested the app, nothing was changed.It works only if I use it in the appDelegate and it applies to all view viewcontrollers.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to your app's didFinishLaunching to achieve the desired effect:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

or in Swift

```
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage()
```